# OSX - Unidentified Developer and bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)

Tags: xcode, frameworks, sign

I am trying to Archive an App for Distribution using Developer ID to run on Mac OSX.

It builds fine and finishes all the processes, but when I try to run the App it shows me an `Unidentified Developer` Message.

I tried to use `--deep` signing in `Other code signing flags` and it returns a `bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)` error during the building process.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem deleting the `ParseLiveQuery.framework`, rebuilding it using Carthage and recompiling the App changing the App version and build.